# Rebuild Raid 6 Array instructions

Tags: raid

I have an HP Server with a HP P400 Controller with 8 72GB drives in a Raid 6 array.

I had a drive fail and replaced it, but it did not rebuild because I have Hard Read errors on 2 other drives, so I am essentially running raid 5 now.

It is my understanding that I will now have to do a backup and restore and replace the 2 drives with hard read errors. I don't think the hard read errors on the 2 drives can be repaired - I wish I could repair one of them, but I don't know how that could be done. Am I correct?

My question is: Can I power down the server and replace the 2 drives (I've already replaced the one drive that did not rebuild).

After replacing the 2 drives, perform a Restore from Backup or will I need to break the Raid Array and recreate it?

The Server is running fine now but a failure in the future is certain. I may wait until it actually fails.

If I have to rebuild the Array can you point me towards instructions.

Thank you for any opinion or suggestions.

Comment: You could image the server, replace the drives, build a new RAID6 and restore the image.

Comment: After you've rebuilt your array, investigate how to enable **Data Scrubbing** to detect bad blocks before they are needed during a rebuild http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Data_scrubbing_.2F_Patrol_read

Answer (score 5):

Raid 6 means you have 2 drives that can fail before data-loss.  If you removed 1 due to failure... and have 2 more with read-errors... your data is probably corrupted.

Whatever method you used to initially build the RAID should also have a tool to rebuild/reassemble the raid with your new disks.  Without knowing more details about your hardware, I can't be more specific.

Comment: The data does not appear to be corrupt. The Server is running fine an it appears 7 of the 8 disks are still participating in the Array. I have just finished an offsite backup and I am using a new Backup software (Acronis Backup and Recovery Virtual Edition).